# delete duplicate entry from file with above some line

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have file whose content like below

```
# Time: 180110 10:48:37
use 65_ebccrmproduction;
SET timestamp=1515561517;
abcdegh
# Time: 180110 10:48:59
SET timestamp=1515561554;
poiuyt
assadd
# Time: 180110 10:49:51
SET timestamp=1515561554;
assddpoiuyt
# Time: 180110 10:49:51
SET timestamp=1515561554;
poiuytassassas
```

I want to grep and delete block whose content match

**block means content between #Time to next #Time**

for example I want to match **poiuyt**

then it will delete below line

```
# Time: 180110 10:48:59
SET timestamp=1515561554;
poiuyt
assadd
# Time: 180110 10:49:51
SET timestamp=1515561554;
poiuytassassas
```

I have code `sed -n '/poiuyt/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' test.txt | sed '/^$/d'` this will delete pattern match and one line above that pattern but my purpose is totally different from this.

**Note :  This should also delete poiuytassassas**

Comment: something like this `sed 's/^# Time:.*/\n&/g' inputfile |awk -v RS= '!/poiuyt/{print $0}'` ?

Comment: yes. Make it in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/^# Time:.*/\n&/g' inputfile |awk -v RS= '!/poiuyt/{print $0}'
```

Here, `sed` is used to properly divide the records, and `awk` is used to do the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/# Time:/{ 
         if (f && !del){ print lines } 
         lines=$0; del=0; f=1; next 
    }
    f{ 
        lines=lines ORS $0; 
        if (/poiuyt/){ del=1 } 
    }
    END{ if (f && !del) print lines }' file.txt
```

The output:

```
# Time: 180110 10:48:37
use 65_ebccrmproduction;
SET timestamp=1515561517;
abcdegh
```